# I need to Select an id when a date matches a query

Tags: json, date, filter, jq

**My json.file**

```json
[  
  {
    "id": 0000001,
    "created_at": "2021-01-28T17:29:35.888Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 0000002,
    "created_at": "2020-12-11T17:29:38.655Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 0000003,
    "created_at": "2020-12-11T17:29:37.233Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 0000004,
    "created_at": "2020-03-30T16:23:59.682Z"
  }
]
```

**My Query**

First: I get the date of the day

```
( now | gmtime | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Z")
```

Then: I transform it to an array

```
| strptime("%FT%T.%Z") [0:6] ) as $f
```

Then: I want it to show only the id that matches my condition

```
| map(select(
    .id | $f[0] == (.[].created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[0]) and
          $f[1] == (.[].created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[1])
))
```

What happens is that it shows me all the records if it finds the condition correct. But I need only the id of the one that matches. What would be my mistake?

The result I get:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-01-28T17:29:35.888Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "created_at": "2020-12-11T17:29:38.655Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "created_at": "2020-12-11T17:29:37.233Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "created_at": "2020-03-30T16:23:59.682Z"
  }
]
```

The result I expect:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-01-28T17:29:35.888Z"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
( now | gmtime | strftime("%Y-%m") ) as $this_month
| .[]
| select( .created_at | startswith($this_month) )
```

[jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/uQ9fcixoAA)

The rest of this answer addresses the OP's code.

---

**Problem #0**

Not really a problem, but a lot of necessary work is being done. `gmtime` already returns an array of the date-time components, so

```
now | gmtime | strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Z") | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[0:6]
```

aka

```
now | gmtime | strftime("%FT%T.%Z") | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[0:6]
```

simplifies to

```
now | gmtime[0:6]
```

Also, the slice is uneeded.

```
now | gmtime
```

Caveat: In this new version, the seconds component is fractional (e.g. 23.489198923110962) instead of integral (e.g. 23), but that's not a problem for us.

---

**Problem #1**

`.id.[].created_at` makes no sense.

```
.id | $f[0] == ( .[].created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[0] ) and
      $f[1] == ( .[].created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[1] )
```

should be

```
$f[0] == ( .created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[0] ) and
$f[1] == ( .created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[1] )
```

This is the same as the following: (Just my preference)

```
( .created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[0] ) == $f[0] and
( .created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[1] ) == $f[1]
```

We can factor out `.created_at`.

```
.created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[0] == $f[0] and
              strptime("%FT%T.%Z")[1] == $f[1]
```

We can factor out the call to `strptime` as well.

```
.created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z") | .[0] == $f[0] and .[1] == $f[1]
```

This nets us this:

```
( now | gmtime ) as $f 
| map(select( .created_at | strptime("%FT%T.%Z") | .[0] == $f[0] and .[1] == $f[1] ))
```

[jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/LmNE2KnxQz)

---

**Problem #2**

We need to flatten the array.

```
... | map(select(...))
```

should be

```
... | map(select(...)) | .[]
```

Of course, we could flatten first, allowing us to eliminate to use of `map`.

```
... | .[] | select(...)
```

This nets us this:

```
( now | gmtime ) as $f 
| .[]
| select(
   .created_at
   | strptime("%FT%T.%Z")
   | .[0] == $f[0] and .[1] == $f[1]
)
```

[jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/iB-bNfRTkG)